# How can I asynchronously save data every 3 minutes using jQuery or PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am writing a online text editor application, and i need to save data to mongo db every 3 minutes after last key press by user currently i am saving data after the textarea loses focus thats fine but i need to add more user friendly features  so i need to add the above functionality but i cant figure out how to go about it i need a timer in jquery which can trigger the ajax call after 180 sec. Can anyone tell me which jquery function i can use to get the desired result. i am using on server side and mongo db as database.

Comment: No one expects perfection, but please try to use proper capitalization and spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({...});
}, 180000);
```

---

However, I'd use an approach that only saves when necessary, and in this case more often. The following example uses functions from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', _.throttle(_.debounce(function() {
    $.ajax(...);
}, 2000), 60000));
```

This will save your data as soon as the user stops typing for at least 2 seconds, but not more than once every minute. Here's a small example which saves every 2s after a modification every 10 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/AagFC/

Comment: Sir what is difference between window.setInterval and self.setInterval

Comment: `self` does not exist. If you use `var self = this;` in a function which does not have `this` mapped to some object, `self === this === window` will be the case, i.e. it will be the same.

Comment: sir i think making ajax call would not be very efficient solution so i want the data to be saved in a variable and then when user clicks save the then i will make just one ajax call so how can i do this ??

Comment: Using AJAX **is** a good solution. The user's browser might crash or he might accidentally close it. In both reasons the user would be screwed. So, unless you want to use something like localStorage storing drafts on the server is the way to go.